# How can I search a Google sheet and return the row?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, google-sheets

Just getting into mobile programming and googling hasn't helped me.

What I am trying to do is make a bar code reader. I have found examples of it online using vision and such. Got that working fine.

Now here is what I am trying to do. Column A has all of the barcodes.  Column B has the item number my company uses. Column C has the item description.

Once I have the input from the scanner, take that number and search the Google sheet. If it gets a match, it will return the information from column B and C from that same row.

As a novice programmer, I kind of need a base to work off of but am having trouble finding anything.

Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For security reasons (API keys are required), Google recommends not to call its Workspace APIs from mobile apps, but from server side applications only. Documentation for server side access is here: [Sheets API - Java Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/java). You can do this also from an Android app, but the steps are a bit more involved, as documented here: [Google Workspace APIs for Android](https://developers.google.com/workspace/guides/android).  For a blog see e.g. [Setup Google Sheets API for Android](https://code.luasoftware.com/tutorials/google-sheets-api/setup-google-sheets-api-for-android/), which points to another article for setting up the authorization.